# 2 domain classes for 1 controller in grails?

Tags: grails, dns

Is it possible to have 2 domain objects for one controller. In that case, how would you map them.

For eg. If I have LoginController, and 2 domain classes for the same viz Login.groovy and LoginSearch.groovy.

In such a case how would you map them?

Comment: You can use as many different domain classes as you desire, but what exactly do you mean by mapping? Persisiting? Or just handling them? I have a vague guess on what you want to do and the answer would be inheritance or interfacing, but could you provide some controller and/or domain code?

Comment: Actually just wanted to know if this is a normal scenario in grails and how this is handled. Thanks air_blob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite clear on what you want but here's my best shot. Controllers do not “map” domain classes; they are just a way to separate the domain class from the view. A controller can reference anywhere from 0 to unlimited domain classes. Most of the logic for crud operations is handled under the covers. If you need to have your domain class use a specific table name, or column names check out the following.
http://www.grails.org/GORM+-+Mapping+DSL
If your question is how can you generate a controller and views for default crud operations that change multiple domain classes at once this is not possible. Your best bet would be to run

```
Grails generate-all com.company.Login.groovy
Grails generate-all com.company.LoginSearch.groovy
```

Then look at the generated code and use it as a template for creating your own controller and associated views that will allow you to reference both domain classes from the same controller.